# How to pop all view controllers except one?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Let I have `FirstViewController`. From `FirstViewController`, user opens **modally** `UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondViewController())`. From `SecondViewController`, user can go further and further using `pushViewController` method. During this travel, user comes to `FifthViewController`, where close button exists as a `leftBarButtonItem`. When it is pressed, I want to show `FirstViewController`, not `SecondViewController`. How to achieve this using best practice?

My idea:
From `FifthViewController`, it is possible to use `popToRootViewController` method. It will show `SecondViewController`. In SecondViewController, I need to somehow handle this (I don't know how) and dismiss it. But I don't think that this method is correct. Also, this method is long, because SecondViewController is shown (that can be possibly avoided). So, what is the best way?

Comment: First of all, your rootViewController has been set to SecondViewController not FirstViewController. Just change rootViewController to FirstViewController and then popToRootViewController will work.

Comment: Can you write your suggestion with more details?

Comment: did you try `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`?

Comment: You can add FirstViewController to navigation stack and hide the navigation bar if it is not required in FirstVC. Then  popToRootViewController will work from FifthViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is call `self.dismiss` on any of the children of navigation controller. This will remove all of your pushed view controllers in UINavigationController and dismiss the UINavigationController itself.

Comment: Interesting idea. Will try!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the navigation stack in `navigationController?.viewControllers`. Take the viewController you are looking for and use

`navigationController?.popToViewController(someViewController, animated: true)`

to go back.

Comment: No, I think you didn't understand question or I didn't understand your solution :) The viewController I want to show not in a stack here.